# Why regularization parameter called as lambda in theory and alpha in python?

Tags: python, terminology, lasso, regularization, ridge-regression

I was learning about regularization and came across the term called `regularization parameter`.

I see that it is called `lambda` in theory but when I looked at the python implementation, I see that it is denoted as `alpha`. Here is the [link1](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html) and [link2](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html)

Am I right to understand that both mean the same?

Is there any difference between regularization paramter lambda and regularization parameter alpha ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No difference. It's just a symbol. Sometimes mathematics uses symbols by convention, but there's no rule or requirement that you must use a certain symbol for a concept.

In this particular case, the word `lambda` is reserved by the Python language, so `alpha` avoids overlapping with that word.

As an aside, one sharp corner in `sklearn` is that `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression` uses the *inverse* of regularization strength as the regularization parameter, so $C=\lambda^{-1}$. In a different package, you might set $\lambda=10$, but for this class, you would get an equivalent result with $C=0.1$.